# how to do Validation Require for image field in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{
    type:'uploader',
    label:'Image',
    name:'images',
    isVisible: true,
    defaultValue: [],
    errorMessage: 'image is required',
    required: true,
    showError: false,
    module: 'restaurants',
    imageType: 'single'
}
```

above like i put the image field validation, but it does not work

Comment: Help us help you. What is the question?

Comment: `<input type="file" required/>` ?

Comment: @MorKadosh how to give a validation image field ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />

onChangeFile = event => {
const image = event.target.files[0];
if (!image) {
 console.log('image is required');
 return false;
 }
 if (!image.name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
   console.log('select valid image.');
  return false;
 }
```

try this.